# calling a php object method on clicking a button?

Tags: php, jquery, oop

I've been working on php application and I've used a OO programming so far to develop it . I have declared a class like this

```
<?php 
class User
{
    public function Add_element()
    {
        //adds some element 
    }

    public function Delete_Element($element_ID)
    {
        //delete the element with that ID
    }
}
?>
```

I've created an object of user class (*for example `$user = new User()`*) in my `index.php` file which includes my `view.index.php` and the `view.index` file is organized as follow

```
<html>
   <header></header>
   <body>
   <input type="button" id="ID"  value='Delete Element' >
   </body>
<html>
```

I know this question may seem repetitious but I want to know how can I call the `$user->Delete_element($ID)` method upon clicking the button .

Comment: Well, you either make it into a standard form with a value that gets passed in a request to a PHP script that does the deleting, or you use AJAX to make the request without coming off the page, or you just make a link that makes a request with relevant params. You can't directly call PHP from Javascript on the client.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive with the AJAX case . I have seen half dozen of samples of them ,  but they all seem to run a php file on js call , not a specific php function on a class!

Comment: Of course they don't. JS is running client-side, while PHP is running server side, the two can't communicate directly. Using AJAX, the JS isn't calling a PHP file, it's making a standard HTTP request to a web server, which may or may not pass onto PHP, and may or may not have a php extension, the JS only cares about the response from the web server, what its return code was, and the content returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something along these lines:

First of all use a form:

```
<form method="POST" action="delete.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="element_id" value="id">
    <input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete element">
</form>
```

And create the following php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['element_id']))
{
    $element_id = intval($_POST['element_id']);
    $user->deleteElement($element_id);
}
```

OR use ajax, which is a bit more complicated.

Edit:
If you do not want to refresh the page you should use AJAX. Start off by including jQuery, which makes this a lot easier. Now you need something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    var data = {};
    data.element_id = $(this).find("[name='element_id']").val();
    $.POST("delete.php", data).done(function(response){
        alert(response);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page for deleting the item.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a bit of javascript which does this.

Answer (score 0):

edit your html file (change the "input" tag to an html form):

```
<form action="Delete_Element.php" method="POST">
    <input type="button" name="ID" value='123456789' >
</form>
```

create a new php page called "Delete_Element.php":

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_POST["ID"]) )
    {
        /* init the "user" object, assuming it is init to: $myUser  */
        //this line invokes your method, given the posed IP param. .
        $myUser->Delete_Element($_POST["ID"]);
     }
```

Comment: I don't want to refresh the page for deleting the item.